# app crashes on iOS 8 having Core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

When I build the app in Xcode 6 it gives me the following error.

> Data Model Version Compile error, compilation failed for data model at path xcode 6. .MOMD file is missing.

Comment: Have you deleted your xcdatamodeld and created a new one?

Comment: No, It's not working with the Old one. But I have also checked this case. I have deleted and re created new one but again same error.

Comment: are u using git? can u delete your local projekt and clone it from your repo again?

Comment: Actually I have not been using the git or svn version. I am using simple version it happens with xcode 6 and iOS 8.

Comment: You could try to clean your poject. Or: Create a new Project, and copy all your files into the new folder.